# Getting the real path of the current directory when using symlinks

Tags: cmd.exe, symbolic-link

So I just found out that my build fails on the build server (Windows 2008 R2) because the workspace is located on a different drive using symlinks.

The build path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProjectTestBuild\workspace` but it actually leads to `d:\Jenkins\jobs\MyProjectTestBuild\workspace\` because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs` is a symlink to `D:\Jenkins\jobs`.

So for whatever reason, my build never terminates when running from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProjectTestBuild\workspace` but completes fine when running in the real location.

So the question is: **How can I find out the real location of the current directory so I can cd into it before running the build script**?

---

**Edit:**

I know how to check the location of a symbolic link. That is not the question. I want to know, given a path, where the real location is. No matter if there might be any symlinks down the path chain.

Comment: That's not the same question. I know how to check where a symbolic link points at. I want to know, given the current path, what the real location is. No matter if there might be any symlinks in the path chain. I think Linux has something like a `realpath` command. But how do I do it on windows?

Comment: I'm reading this, and I keep thinking "yes, that's exactly what you want". Where a symbolic link points is the "real path". I would guess that's what others are thinking too. Perhaps further explanation will make it more clear how that differs from what you want.

Comment: No, I think I was pretty clear. The symbolic link points to a folder that is just a part of the real path. The link is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs` and points to `D:\Jenkins\jobs`. The current path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProjectTestBuild\workspace`. And the real path is `D:\Jenkins\jobs\MyProjectTestBuild\workspace`. I have currently solved the problem by doing a hard coded `cd` to the actual build directory, but I would prefer a more general solution. Preferably one that does not break if someone renames `MyProjectTestBuild`.